# WCF Error - 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I have facing above error after adding the maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" parameter both server and client.
However in my project large number of data can transferred using "datatable" objects without any issue.
This error occurred large number of data transferred with using "List<>" objects.
My dotnetframework is 4.0, but I found this error NOT found in dotnetframework 4.5 and large number of data can transferring using "List<>" object without error. Also this is Windows base project.

Please anyone can solved this problem. Here are the my server and client app.cofig configurations.

Thanks!!!

My Service;

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CommonBehavior">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceThrottling
          maxConcurrentSessions="1200"
          maxConcurrentCalls="192"
          maxConcurrentInstances="1392"
           />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>

      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" name="netTcpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" listenBacklog="2000" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647"  maxConnections="2000"
                       closeTimeout="08:00:00" openTimeout="08:00:00" receiveTimeout="08:00:00" sendTimeout="08:00:00">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"  maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxArrayLength="2147483647"  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="08:00:00"
             enabled="false" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType ="None"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>


  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="CommonBehavior" name="MyBLL">
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding" name="MyEndPoint" contract="IMy">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/MySVC"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My Client;

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint name="MyEndPoint" address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/MySVC" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding" contract="IMy" />
  </client>

  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CommonBehavior">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="netTcpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" listenBacklog="2000" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647"  maxConnections="2000"
               closeTimeout="08:00:00" openTimeout="08:00:00" receiveTimeout="08:00:00" sendTimeout="08:00:00">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"  maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxArrayLength="2147483647"  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="08:00:00"
             enabled="false" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType ="None"/>
        </security>

      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="CommonBehavior" name="MyEndPoint">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="CommonBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding" name="MyEndPoint" contract="Imy">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/MySVC" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Max received message size is 2GB? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have reduce it for 512 mb. but its not working..!!

Comment: Why do you have a `<services>` section in your client config?  It should be `<client>`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have removed <services> section in client config also  I found my mistake in <client> section. Thanks your great support Tim..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my mistake in client config and **I was solved my problem**.

My mistake was ***behaviorConfiguration="CommonBehavior"*** tag not in the *client, endpoint* section. After added this part the problem was successfully solved and **large number of records** exist **generic list** I can transferred from server to client.

This is my corrected client config -

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint name="MyEndPoint" behaviorConfiguration="CommonBehavior" address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/MySVC" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding" contract="IMy" />
  </client>

  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CommonBehavior">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="netTcpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" listenBacklog="2000" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647"  maxConnections="2000"
               closeTimeout="08:00:00" openTimeout="08:00:00" receiveTimeout="08:00:00" sendTimeout="08:00:00">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"  maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxArrayLength="2147483647"  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="08:00:00"
             enabled="false" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType ="None"/>
        </security>

      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```